# I have min and max number how can I generate n number of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have `min` number `10.5` and `max` number `29.75` I want to generate `n` number of array from these two ranges. I am generating the array with `interval` already below but how can I calculate `interval`:

```
generateArrayMinMax(min, max, interval) {
   if (interval === 0 || interval < 0) interval = 1;
   let list = [];
   for (var i = min; i <= max; i = i + interval) {
      list.push(i);
   }
   return list;
}

let min = 10.05;
let max = 29.75;
let arrayLen = 20;
let result = generateArrayMinMax(10.05, 29.75, 20);
```

Expected Result:

```
[10.5, 11.513157894736842, 12.526315789473685, 13.539473684210526, 14.552631578947368, 15.56578947368421, 16.57894736842105, 17.592105263157894, 18.605263157894736, 19.61842105263158, 20.63157894736842, 21.64473684210526, 22.657894736842103, 23.671052631578945, 24.684210526315788, 25.69736842105263, 26.710526315789473, 27.723684210526315, 28.736842105263158, 29.75]
```

I need to calculate the interval to achieve that is there any method for that.
Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the interval with the delta and the wanted parts.

```js
function generateArrayMinMax(min, max, n) {
   let list = [min],
       interval = (max - min) / (n - 1);

   for (let i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
      list.push(min + interval * i);
   }
   list.push(max);                        // prevent floating point arithmetic errors
   return list;
}

console.log(generateArrayMinMax(10.5, 29.75, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be a few more solutions for this question, here is how I would do it:

```
const min = 10.05;
const max = 29.75;
const arrayLen = 20;

const generateArray = (min: number, max: number, n: number) => {
    // here you can play with some Math.round to make your interval integer or not
    const interval = (max - min) / (n - 1);
    const initial = new Array(n).fill(min);
    return initial.map((value, index) => index * interval + value);
};

const result = generateArray(min, max, arrayLen);
console.info('OUTPUT', result.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula for calculating the value at position `i` in the output array is:

```js
(max - min) / (interval - 1) * i + min
```

```js
function generateArrayMinMax(min, max, interval) {
  const formula = (_, i) => (max - min) / (interval - 1) * i + min;
  return Array.from({ length: interval }, formula);
}

console.log(generateArrayMinMax(10.5, 29.75, 5));
```

If you like to play codegolf:

```js
f = (a, b, l) => Array.from({ length: l }, (_, i) => (b - a) / (l - 1) * i + a);

console.log(f(10.5, 29.75, 5));
```

Not pretty, but still nicer than the loops in the currently accepted answer.