# Get from one number to another number

Tags: javascript

Given a number, say `1.2`, is there a simple way in JavaScript, to get to `-1.5` in steps of `.1`. Or from say `-50.3` to `12.3`.

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easier way of doing this then writing a bunch of complex if statements.

Comment: Use a `for` loop? But watch out for floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: What does it mean to go from `1.2` to `-1.5` in `.1` steps?

Comment: Add or subtract in a loop?

Comment: @GirkovArpa = given 1.2 as the start value and -1.5 as the end value, then the result would be 1.1,1.0,.9,.8.... to -1.5

Comment: The only `if` statement you need is to test whether you're going up or down. You can use different loops depending on the direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have min and max number how can I generate n number of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842169/i-have-min-and-max-number-how-can-i-generate-n-number-of-array)

Comment: What exactly is the goal here?

Comment: `for (let i = 1.2; i > -1.5; i -= 0.1) console.log(i);`???

Comment: @JohnMontgomery He wants to generate an array of numbers from `x` to `y` in increments of `z`.

Comment: @GirkovArpa That question is about knowing the number of steps and determining the delta. In this question the delta is known.

Comment: Ah you're right.  I had not realized the distinction.

Comment: @GirkovArpa I don't see anything about arrays in the question.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The OP has posted the example output of: `1.1,1.0,.9,.8...-1.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid accumulating floating point inaccuracies (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)) it would be best to multiply your numbers by `10` and then use steps of `1`. You can then divide by `10` when generating the results.

Then you just need two `for` loops: one for counting up, the other for counting down.

```js
function range(start, end) {
  start = Math.round(start * 10);
  end = Math.round(end * 10);
  result = [];
  if (start > end) { // counting down
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i--) {
      result.push(i / 10);
    }
  } else { // counting up
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      result.push(i / 10);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(range(1.2, -1.5));
console.log(range(-50.3, 12.3));
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar - exactly what I just spent the last few hours trying to get working!

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (let number = -10.5; number < 10.5; number += 0.1) {
    realPart = number - (number - Math.floor(number));
    decimalPart = Math.floor((number - Math.floor(number)) * 10) / 10;
    console.log( realPart + decimalPart);
}

// or

for (let number = 10.5; number > -10.5; number -= 0.1) {
    realPart = number - (number - Math.floor(number));
    decimalPart = Math.floor((number - Math.floor(number)) * 10) / 10;
    console.log( realPart + decimalPart);
}
```